# JAX python C callbacks

Tags: python, numba, jax

Numba allows to create C-callbacks directly in python with the
@cfunc-decorator ( https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.42.0/user/cfunc.html ):

```
@cfunc("float64(float64)") 
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

To clarify, the resulting function is a pure C-function, which can then be called directly from C-code.

Is there an equivalent functionality available in JAX ( https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/# )?

I have been searching for a while but couldn't find anything. I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Maybe try [taichi](https://www.taichi-lang.org) which I think supports autodiff and c callbacks - [relevant docs](https://docs.taichi-lang.org/docs/tutorial). as for autodiff in numba there's [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8565) discussing it.

Comment: there's also [numba4jax](https://github.com/PhilipVinc/numba4jax) i'm not sure if cfuncs are supported though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JAX doesn't provide any API similar to Numba's `cfunc`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!.
It's a shame that it's missing... It's a useful feature of numba, but since auto-diff is missing in numba I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a missing feature – you should keep in mind the architectural differences between Numba and JAX: Numba is basically a Python-to-C transpiler, so `cfunc` is a pretty natural API to provide. JAX is a Python-to-HLO/XLA compiler, with no explicit C APIs in it's toolchain, so `cfunc` is not really an API that makes sense in that context.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought of that. I don't know how JAX functions; I presumed it would generate some so/dll that is callable from c and then wrap it for python.